Statically Indeterminate Cantilever Beam, with gap between roller support when unloaded

In the unloaded configuration the roller support at B, does not touch the beam but has a gap of 10mm. When loaded the beam and support are in contact.
I am a little stuck with the problem, and have been attempting to solve it using singularity functions as follows:
$ Mx = -R_A\langle x\rangle ^1 + R_B \langle x-4 \rangle ^1- \frac{4}{2} \langle x-2 \rangle ^2 + \frac{4}{2} \langle x-4 \rangle ^2$
Integrating once :
$ EI y' = \frac{R_A}{2}  \langle x \rangle ^2 - \frac{R_B}{2} \langle x-4 \rangle ^2 + \frac{2}{3}  \langle x-2 \rangle ^3   - \frac{2}{3} \langle x-6 \rangle ^3 + C_1$
Twice :
$ EIy  = \frac{R_A}{6}x^3 - \frac{R_B}{6} \langle x-4 \rangle ^3 + \frac{2}{12} \langle x 
- 2 \rangle ^4 - \frac{2}{12} \langle x-6 \rangle ^4 + C_1x +C_2 $
I am given that $E = 200GPa$ and $I = 30 * 10^6 mm^4$
With Boundary Conditions $x=0 \quad and \quad y=0$,
$x=0 \quad and \quad y' = 0  $
$C_2 = 0 \quad and \quad C_1 = 0 $
I am unsure how to proceed further and find the reaction forces at A and B

I do not know for sure, but this sounds a lot like the need for the Virtual work method, but I could be completely wrong.

a simple way of solving this is to work out the deflection at B for a point force applied at B. Then remove B, estimate the deflection at B in response to the given loading. Then supply sufficient upward force at B to give a 10mm deflection.
The stiffness at B is simply k=3 * E * I/Lab^3
For the run with RB=0 then RA =26000, which you can plug into your equation, if it is right (I don't think it is but am not sure- why is there an RA term in there at all?), at x=4, to get a deflection yb, then you need to add RB=k*(abs(y)-10mm) and RA obviously drops.
Note that mixing m and mm is alway trouble unless you are using MathCAD or the like.
Your results should look like this

So I used skyciv. The above plots are correct (sign conventions may not be). here's the deflection plot, 10mm down at 4m, tip deflection just over 90 mm

